# Insert lists into mysql in column wise in python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

i have 3 list

```
list1=[3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
list2=[1, 10, 5, 2, 1]
list3=[5, 53, 26, 11, 5]
```

how to insert this data into mysql database in column wise. each list should be stored in a column.I knew to store it row wise using `cursor.executemany(sqlquery,lists)`. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only using `cursor.executemany`. So you can transform three lists into one by combining data from the same position.

```
list1=[3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
list2=[1, 10, 5, 2, 1]
list3=[5, 53, 26, 11, 5]
print(list(zip(list1,list2,list3)))
# [(3, 1, 5), (4, 10, 53), (5, 5, 26), (6, 2, 11), (9, 1, 5)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `pandas`:

**Convert the lists into a Pandas dataframe**:

```
In [1644]: df = pd.DataFrame({'list1':list1,'list2':list2,'list3':list3})

In [1645]: df
Out[1645]: 
   list1  list2  list3
0      3      1      5
1      4     10     53
2      5      5     26
3      6      2     11
4      9      1      5
```

**Use `to_sql` method to write into mysql table**:

```
df.to_sql(con=con, name='mytable', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql')
```